# EF4 - Many to many relationship, querying with contains and List<int>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, contains

I have an asp.net C# application using EF4 to connect to a SQL Server database.

In the database I have a many to many relationship between two tables, `Officer` and `Geography` - so another table called `OfficerGeography` exists which connects the two.

With this database used to create an edmx diagram, EF4 correctly sees the many to many relationship between these two tables.

**The problem**
I have an `List<int>` of geographyIds, which correspond to the primary key of the `Geography` table.

I wish to use this list to retrieve officers that have a geographyId that appear in this list. I thought the following LINQ would work:

```
var geographyIds = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var officers = db.Officers.Where(o => o.Enabled == true && geographyIds.Contains(o.Geographies.GeographyId));
```

However this fails. In fact intellisense won't list any columns for `o.Geographies` (because of the many to many relationship).

How can I retrieve a list of Officers where they have a GeographyId match?

**Additional clarification**
The `OfficerGeography` database table does not appear as it's own entity in EF4. EF4 correctly sees only `Officer` and `Geography`, with a navigation property from one to the other on both entities.

Comment: Do you have an `OfficerGeography` entity on the edmx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
var officers = db.Officers
    .Where(o => o.Enabled == true 
        && o.Geographies.Any(g => geographyIds.Contains(g.Id)));
```

geographyIds.Contains() takes one int as parameter but each officer may have several geographies, therefor the any-method is used to check them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Did EF map the join table as a relationship or is it included as an entity?

If it has been included as an entity, you may need to try

```
o.OfficerGeographies.GeographyId
```

This isn't the whole answer, though.  If the `OfficerGeographies` table is mapped to an entity on your edmx, then you should remove it and add a relationship / association between your `Officer` and `Geography` tables and map that relationship to the join table.

Comment: @kirk-broadhurst the `OfficerGeographies` table doesn't appear as an entity. EF4 only sees the many to many relationship between `Officer` and `Geographies`. Each of these entities have the other as navigation property.